# Simple proof that $\min \|\mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}_i}\|$ is given by $\lambda_i = \langle \mathbf{f}, \hat{\mathbf{g}}_i \rangle$

Tags: vectors, orthonormal

Let $\mathbf{f}$ be a real valued vector and $\{\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\}$ be a set of orthonormal vectors of the same dimension. What is a simple proof that

$$\min \|\mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}_i}\|$$

is given by $\lambda_i = \langle \mathbf{f}, \hat{\mathbf{g}}_i \rangle$

This is my attempt:

$$\min \|\mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\|$$
$$ = \min \|\mathbf{f}\|^2 + \|\sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\|^2 - 2\langle\mathbf{f},\sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$

Since

$$\|\sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\|^2 = \langle\sum_i\lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i,\sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$
$$ = \sum_i\sum_j\langle\lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i, \lambda_j\hat{\mathbf{g}}_j\rangle$$
$$ = \sum_i\langle\lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i, \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$
$$ = \sum_i\lambda_i^2$$

Thus 
$$\min \|\mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}_i}\| = \min \sum_i \lambda_i^2 - 2\langle\mathbf{f},\sum_i \lambda_i\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$
$$ = \min \sum_i \lambda_i^2 - 2 \sum_i \lambda_i\langle\mathbf{f},\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$

Since at the minimum we have

$$\frac{d}{d\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \sum_i \lambda_i^2 - 2 \sum_i \lambda_i\langle\mathbf{f},\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle = 0$$

Taking partial derivative w.r.t. $\lambda_i$ we get

$$2 \lambda_i - 2 \langle\mathbf{f},\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle = 0$$
$$\lambda_i = \langle\mathbf{f},\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rangle$$

but is there something simpler?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: An arbitrary $\mathbf{f}$ can be expressed uniquely as $\mathbf{f} = \sum_i \mu_i \mathbf{\hat{g}}_i + \mathbf{f}'$ where $\mathbf{f}'$ is orthogonal to all the $\mathbf{\hat{g}}_i$.

---

**Second hint**: $$\lVert \mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i \hat{\mathbf{g}}_i \rVert^2 = \lVert \mathbf{f}'\rVert^2 + \sum_i \lVert (\mu_i - \lambda_i)\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i\rVert^2$$

---

**Summary of a solution**: Using the above two hints, we find that

$$\lVert \mathbf{f} - \sum_i \lambda_i \hat{\mathbf{g}}_i  \rVert^2 =  \lVert \mathbf{f}'\rVert^2 + \sum_i |\mu_i - \lambda_i|^2$$

This is a sum of a constant and a series of positive numbers, so it is minimized if we can make those positive numbers zero. We can: $\lambda_i = \mu_i$. But looking back at the first hint, $\mu_i = \langle \hat{\mathbf{g}}_i, \mathbf{f} \rangle$ so we're done.

Comment: My proof expands everything out and sets partial derivates wrt $\lambda_i$ to 0 to find them but it is pretty unsatisfying... A bigger hint perhaps? :)

Comment: Answer updated with the next stage.

Comment: hehe Math.SE is the only SE site where people give hints instead of answers. Anyway I've updated question with my method.

Comment: Did you try using my second hint at all?

Comment: Not sure where to go sorry. I found if I write it all in matrix form it is pretty concise, but I'm interested to see your method.

Comment: I've written down what I was intending.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't $\mathbf{f}'$ a function of $\mu_i$, not a constant?

Comment: @geometrikal Both $\mathbf{f}'$ and $\mu_i$ are specified by your given data $\mathbf{f}$. If you like, they're both constant. (Remember you're only varying $\lambda_i$, not $\mu_i$.) In case you're getting confused, the prime does not represent differentiation, it's just a label saying it's "a bit of $\mathbf{f}$".

Answer (score 0):

As a function of $\lambda_i$, the norm is convex in each $\lambda_i$. Picking $\lambda_i=\langle f,g_i\rangle$ gives a value of 0 for the norm. Since norms are non-negative, you're done.

Comment: I don't think that there are necessarily enough $\hat{\mathbf{g}}_i$s to form a basis, the number of them isn't given.  Of course, applying this to the decomposition I suggested might be useful for the OP...